# Error of input cannot be resolved to be a variable and exception in thread main.lang

Tags: java, switch-statement

The following code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TheSwitchState{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
 '   char letter;

    input= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a, b or c:");
    
    letter= input.charAt(0); '

        switch(letter)
        {
                case 'a':
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"please enter a :");
                break;

                case 'b':
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"please enter b :");
                break;

                case 'c':
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"please enter c :");
                break;

                default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Enter characater is invalid !!");
        }
        System.exit(0);

    }
}
```

Gives the following error:

```
<Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
        input cannot be resolved to a variable
        input cannot be resolved

        at TheSwitchState.main(SwitchState.java:8)>
```

Could someone please explain why this error is happening, as well as provide some suggestions as to how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are two floating `'` characters in your code, for some reason. You should remove them, as they are causing errors; I am assuming it was a mistake made when transferring over the code to Stack Overflow.

The error is happening because you have not defined a type for `input`. The return value for `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` should be `String`, so change:

```
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a, b or c:");
```

to

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a, b or c:");
```